# javascript Insert a new row in a table with 2 headers

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a table that looks like this :

```
<button onclick="addRow()">Add a Row</button>
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">My header</th>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <th>header</th>
    <td>cell1</td>
    <td>cell2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I am trying to create a javascript function to add new rows to the table that would match the last row.

```
<script>
function addRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rows);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML = "header";
  cell2.innerHTML = "cell1";
  cell3.innerHTML = "cell2";
}
</script>
```

After spending a good amount of time on google trying to figure it out. I must say I could not find what I am looking for. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `insertCell()` only creates `<td>` tags, so you need to use `document.createElement` to create the `<th>` tag for your first cell.

```html
<button onclick="addRow()">Add a Row</button>

<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">My header</th>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <th>header</th>
    <td>cell1</td>
    <td>cell2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
function addRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rows);
  var cell1 = document.createElement("TH");
  row.appendChild(cell1);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML = "header";
  cell2.innerHTML = "cell1";
  cell3.innerHTML = "cell2";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for your quick reply, my problem is that cell1 remains as <td> instead of <th> and I am using bootstrap for this project. This means that just putting the header in bold won't do the job due to CSS. Also I already have a way to call the function, just thought it wasn't needed for the question. I'll edit my question and add a button in the html part.

Comment: Edited my answer to give you a <th> tag instead of just making the first element bold.